# "File in use" locked by "another user" - how can I know which user opened the file?

Tags: microsoft-office, file-unlocking

As an administrator I can watch all shared files and who opened it, but sometimes users complain they do not know who has it open because Office just says it's opened by "another user".

Do you know the reason or how to fix it?

Comment: Over here, Office tells me who it's locked by

Comment: Sometimes it tells me the user who's editing the file, and others instead the username just "another user".

Comment: same Question here:
http://superuser.com/questions/30980/microsoft-office-document-is-locked-for-editing-by-another-user

Comment: I want the user knows who opened the file. There's not owner files neither Office instances open, just someone else opened the file and I don't know why sometimes the alert shows them the user name or "another user".

Answer (score 0):

The reason is probably going to be specific to each user.  You'll want to check their event logs and see if Office logs the files in use.  Also try to open the file with a different program to make sure it is actually open.

I hesitate to recommend a file unlocker as it merely cures the symptom but not the problem.  In any case, there are 100s of file unlockers. The one I use is Process Explorer.

There are just too many reasons and factors to go over. The files could legitimately be used by another user. By another process. You'll need to be more specific or provide a real error message.