# Several Word & Excel files are not opening and report "locked for editing by another user"

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word

When I try to open a Word file, it reports **error: xyz.doc is locked by editing by 'another user".**

I'm using Office 2007 and the errors are mainly with files which are *"Microsoft Office Word 97 - 2003 Document (.doc)"* format.

Also when I check the properties I get a security warning: "*The file came from another computer and blocked to protect this computer*".

Similarly, some Excel files are not working. What could be the cause?

Comment: Related question: SU: 2009-08-27, [*Microsoft Office document is “locked for editing by 'another user'”*](https://superuser.com/questions/30980/microsoft-office-document-is-locked-for-editing-by-another-user)

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have opened the file multiple times. If you did, close all Word / Excel instances and try again.
If it does not help, restart you computer.
It can also be if you files are in a shared / network drive and they are opened at another computer.

Comment: this is not working......and my pc is not in sharing mode......also ther is no file opened...

Comment: form last one month i m facing this problem nd i have tried many solution whaich are provided on many different site.....help me fix the problem.....

Comment: Try this: Open Word, go to `File > Options > Trust Center > Trust Center Settings > Trusted Locations` and add the path of the documents you have problems with.

Answer (score 0):

Also, check your account environment variables. I just fixed a similar issue on a computer where TMP was set to another user's temporal directory. One would expect these things to be gone on Windows 7/MS Office 2010 but they are still around.
This computer had another weird issue: on a new document, trying to go File|Save as... would not show the dialog (it actually would show nothing at all). So you can check for this symptom before trying anything on TEMP or TMP.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue when my TEMP and TMP environment (paths) were invalid.

You can update them by doing this:

1) Right Click My Computer.  Select Properties.
2) On the left, click Advanced System Settings.  Make sure the Advanced tab is selected.
3) Click the Environment Variables button.

Make sure that the paths to the TMP and TEMP directories are valid (or edit them to make them valid).  Check under both User variables and System variables for TMP and TEMP