# Changing the "file opened by another user" warning timeout

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-office

This is an almost opposite to [this problem](https://superuser.com/questions/30980/microsoft-office-document-is-locked-for-editing-by-another-user)  - My workmate keeps an Excel spreadsheet open for a whole day (she has good reasons to do so) without editing. Now if someone else would like to access this file, the "file is open by another user..." warning should appear, but I've noticed that if the file was left open for a long period of time without any changes made to it, this warning won't show up. This leads to potential issues with the same file being edited at the same time.

Is there a way to change this timout?

Comment: You are probably better off converting this to a database which has the ability to handle multi-user environment build in.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to just copy the data and place it in Microsoft Access. Then split the database keeping the back end on the file share and then send anyone that needs access the file a copy of the front end. That way she can keep the file open all day long and everyone else can open and add data when ever they wish.