# Upload Failed: This file is locked for editing by <my name>

Tags: windows, windows-10, microsoft-office, onedrive

MS Office using OneDrive for Business tells me that I have locked a file for editing. How can I unlock it so that I can use and save it?

Here is what I have tried:

1. Close all open Web browsers (in case of cloud locking).
2. Close all open MS Office programs.
3. Close all open instances of Explorer.
4. Run `handle.exe` > No matching handles found.
5. Restart the computer.
6. Then reopen the file.

[image: FILE IN USE This file is locked for editing by <my name>.]

I have also tried to find the "owner file" as in the answer: https://superuser.com/a/30984/164640

My current workaround is to "Save As" with a `-v2` suffix. Sigh.